# Adding two new elements to a List in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my model, I have the following `Section` class:

```
public partial class Section
{
    public Section()
    {
        Steps = new List<SectionStep>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SortId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Html { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Tutorial_Id { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Tutorial Tutorial { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SectionStep> Steps { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public bool _destroy { get; set; }
}
```

and the following `SectionStep` class:

```
public class SectionStep
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SortId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Html { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool _destroy { get; set; }
}
```

I have an ASP.NET application in which users can edit these, including adding and removing `Section`s and `SectionStep`s.  The data is POSTed to the server via JSON, the server reads this correctly and adds everything just fine.  However, when I add two `SectionStep`s to the same section, I get the following error:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

The JSON POSTed to the server is deserialized into `List<Section> sections`  The following code handles this and adds the appropriate objects to my entity model.

```
        foreach (Section section in sections)
            {                    
                if (section._destroy)
                {
                    // if id is 0, it was never even added
                    if (section.Id > 0)
                        db.Entry(section).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                }
                else if (section.Id == 0)
                {
                    db.Entry(section).State = EntityState.Added;
                }
                else
                {
                    db.Entry(section).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
                foreach (SectionStep step in section.Steps.ToList())
                {                        
                    if (step._destroy)
                    {
                        // if id is 0, it was never even added so don't delete
                        if (step.Id > 0)
                            db.Entry(step).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                        else
                            section.Steps.Remove(step);
                    }
                    else if (step.Id == 0)
                    {
                        db.Entry(step).State = EntityState.Added;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        db.Entry(step).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    }
                }
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            returnSections.AddRange(db.Sections.Where(s => s.Tutorial_Id == tutorial_id).OrderBy(s => s.SortId).ToArray());
```

It seems to me that the problem is that when I add two steps, they both have the same Id for some reason.  At first they do start with Id = 0 because I let the database automatically assign that, but I handle the `Section`s the same way, and adding two `Section`s works just fine.

Comment: Why did you define Id's with [Key] attribute? Then you won't assign 0 to Id. This provides automatically increment in table.

Comment: Entity Framework generated this for me from an existing database. Are you saying I should add the [Key] attribute? I tried adding the [Key] attribute to the Id property in both Section and SectionStep and this didn't change anything.

Comment: Was this ever solved? Is there a way to do this without resorting to iterative/recursive calls?